# How does surrogate call function work?

Tags: c++, templates

Here is the source code similar to the surrogate call functions that I read on the post "Hidden features in C++"

The only part that confuses me is those operator overloaded functions.
What kind of operators are they? (They certainly don't seem like ordinary operator()'s, and why is it returning a function pointer even though there is no return type specified?

Thanks!

```
template <typename Fcn1, typename Fcn2>
class Surrogate {
public:
    Surrogate(Fcn1 *f1, Fcn2 *f2) : f1_(f1), f2_(f2) {}

    // Overloaded operators.
    // But what does this do? What kind of operators are they?
    operator Fcn1*() { return f1_; }
    operator Fcn2*() { return f2_; }

private:
    Fcn1 *f1_;
    Fcn2 *f2_;
};

void foo (int i)
{
    std::cout << "foo: " << i << std::endl;
}

void bar (double i)
{
    std::cout << "bar: " << i << std::endl;
}

int main ()
{
    Surrogate<void(int), void(double)> callable(foo, bar);

    callable(10);       // calls foo
    callable(10.1);     // calls bar

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: basically an instance of the class can be used as a Fcn1* or Fcn2* without casting

Answer (score 9):

They are implicit type conversion operators to Fcn1* and Fcn2*.

In the expression "callable(10)" callable is converted by the compiler to pointer to function with int parameter, using the first one of the type conversion operators defined in Surrogate. That function is then invoked.

Comment: thanks you! I'll google more about implicit  conversion operators

Answer (score 2):

The call `callable(10);` actually is `*(callable.operator void(*)(int))(10);`.

The compiler has figured out that `callable` is used in a function call expression. Now, for a function call expression the compiler would like a function, function pointer, or object with `operator()` - as you already know.

In this case, `callable` is none of these. But `callable` can be *converted* to one of these, namely to a function pointer. Given the call expression, in particular the `int` argument, overload resolution selects `void(*)(int)`.

Answer (score 1):

These are just user-defined conversion operators. User-defined conversion operators is a basic feature of C++ language, meaning that you can read about them in C++ book or in some tutorial.

Section 12.3.2 of language specification describes the syntax, but the rules that govern their usage by the compiler are scattered across the entire document and are relatively extensive. I.e. it is not something that can or should be explained in a SO post.

Find a book. Come back here if something in the book is not clear to you.